# preg_split SKU into sections

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a number of SKUs that I need to split. I only need the colour and number at the end out of the string so the first `SKU-PRODUCT` bit can be ignored from the split. Here's a few examples of the SKUs:

`SKU-PRODUCT-BLUE-1`

`SKU-PRODUCT-RED-1`

`SKU-PRODUCT-WHITE-1`

`SKU-PRODUCT-BABY-BLUE-1`

I have been using `preg_split('/-/', $sku)` but it will split BABY-BLUE up into two sections.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't need the SKU-PRODUCT bit of the string, just the colour and the number at the end. Is it better to just list every colour in the split string?

My expected results are `['BLUE',1]` or `['BABY-BLUE',1]`.

Comment: Not sure whether you want to save the `SKU-PRODUCT` part but this should do it: `^((?:[^-]+-?){2})-(.*)-([0-9]+)$` - https://regex101.com/r/Ycl1mx/1

Comment: @CD001 Hi, i got an error `ERROR: Unknown modifier '-'` when trying that.

Comment: Probably because I just wrote the pattern - not including the delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_match('~^[^-]+-[^-]+-(.+)-([^-]+)$~', $s, $matches)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ICHGUo/5).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^-]+-` - 1 or more chars other than `-` and then `-`
- `[^-]+-` - same as above
- `(.+)` - Group 1: any 1+ chars as many as possible
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([^-]+)` - Group 2: any 1+ chars other than `-` as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/BtnnFa):

```
$strs = ['SKU-PRODUCT-BLUE-1', 'SKU-PRODUCT-RED-1', 'SKU-PRODUCT-WHITE-1', 'SKU-PRODUCT-BABY-BLUE-1'];
foreach ($strs as $s) {
    if (preg_match('~^[^-]+-[^-]+-(.+)-([^-]+)$~', $s, $matches)) {
            print_r(array($matches[1], $matches[2]));
            echo "\n";
    } else {
        echo "No match!";
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Array ( [0] => BLUE [1] => 1 )
Array ( [0] => RED [1] => 1 )
Array ( [0] => WHITE [1] => 1 )
Array ( [0] => BABY-BLUE [1] => 1 )
```

Comment: Thankyou for the speedy reply. It looks like it split BABY-BLUE into 2 words, I am trying to keep it as BABY-BLUE, is this possible?

Comment: My expected results are `['BLUE',1]` or `['BABY-BLUE',1]` In your example it split it as `PRODUCT-BABY`

Comment: Yes, It just returns `['SKU-PRODUCT','']` for each value for me

Comment: @Callum You are not using my code. See the results I get added to the answer. **Use `preg_match`**, not `preg_split`.

Comment: @Callum You cannot use `preg_split` because you do not need a part of the string. You  have to use matching rather than splitting (that is good when you need all the bits of the split string).

Comment: Thank you that has worked. Not sure who down-voted it but I just marked it as an answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
preg_match('/^SKU-(?:[^-]+)-(.*)-(\d+)$/', $input, $matches);
```

where `$input` contains the SKU you want to split (f.e. `'SKU-PRODUCT-BLUE-1'`).

On success (when [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns `TRUE`), `$matches[1]` contains the color and `$matches[2]` contains the number at the end.

Comment: This just gives 2 empty strings

Answer (score -1):

Working on the assumption that `SKU` and `PRODUCT` are not fixed values but **cannot** contain a hyphen (-), the colour is an alpha string which can contain hyphens and that the number is, in fact, just a number.

Since you're not splitting your strings on a *specific* pattern you **cannot** use `preg_split` to achieve what you want - it's the wrong tool for the job. You're going to need to match the entire string on a pattern and extract those parts you need from the resulting `$matches` array.

Using this RegEx:

```
^(?:[^-]+-?){2}-(.*)-([0-9]+)$
```

That matches any non-hyphen character, followed by 0|1 hyphens exactly twice (e.g. *SKU-PRODUCT*) followed by a hyphen, then any character any number of times (the colour), another hyphen and any number of digits.

So, in PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');

$skus = [
    'SKU-PRODUCT-BLUE-1',
    'SKU-PRODUCT-RED-1',
    'SKU-PRODUCT-WHITE-1',
    'SKU-PRODUCT-BABY-BLUE-1'
];

foreach($skus as $sku) {
    $matches = null;
    preg_match('/^(?:[^-]+-?){2}-(.*)-([0-9]+)$/', $sku, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

This results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SKU-PRODUCT-BLUE-1
    [1] => BLUE
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => SKU-PRODUCT-RED-1
    [1] => RED
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => SKU-PRODUCT-WHITE-1
    [1] => WHITE
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => SKU-PRODUCT-BABY-BLUE-1
    [1] => BABY-BLUE
    [2] => 1
)
```

Your colour and number are matching groups 1 and 2 respectively.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use regexp, do this:

```
$a = explode('-', $product)
$_sku = array_shift($a);
$_product = array_shift($a);
$remainder = implode('-', $a);
```

If `SKU` and `PRODUCT` don't have any dashes, this will be effective.

Performance time would not be an issue here.

You could also do:

```
preg_match('/[^-]+-[^-]+(.+)/', $product, $m);
$remainder = $m[1];
```